# Bootstrap multiple inputs inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having difficulty placing two  and one text input in a single row in my form. I am able to get the two selects inline but the text input is being stubborn. Here is how it looks with the current code:

[image]

```
<form role='form' action='#' method='post'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='query-bar' class='sr-only'></label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter search query..' name='query-bar' />
    </div>
    <div class='form-inline'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <select name='builder-columns' class='form-control'>
                <option selected disabled value='none'>Columns</option>
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <select name='builder-operators' class='form-control'>
                <option selected disabled value='none'>Operators</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='builder-filter' class='sr-only'></label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Filter' name='builder-filter' class='form-control' />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
<div class='form-inline row'>
    <div class='form-group col-sm-4'>
        <select name='builder-columns' class='form-control'>
            <option selected disabled value='none'>Columns</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group col-sm-4'>
        <select name='builder-operators' class='form-control'>
            <option selected disabled value='none'>Operators</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group col-sm-4'>
        <label for='builder-filter' class='sr-only'></label>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Filter' name='builder-filter' class='form-control' />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.form-inline .form-control {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The class `row` was added to the `form-inline` elements, and the class `col-sm-4` was added to the `form-group` elements. In addition, the width of the `.form-control` elements was set to `100%` in order to overwrite `width: auto` which is applied at certain screen sizes.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7j0qo0y/)